# Dig inside dictionary

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I need a little help to understand how to dig into a dictionary in autocad.

I've a little discontinued addon for autocad that let me draw some rod inside the drawing but it has some bugs. I want to understand how it works so I can fix them.

I get the list of dictionaries by: 
(entget (namedobjdict)))`

```
((-1 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>) (0 . "DICTIONARY")
                                    (330 . <Nome entità: 0>)
                                    (5 . "C")
                                    (100 . "AcDbDictionary")
                                    (280 . 0)
                                    (281 . 1)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_COLOR")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03bb0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_GROUP")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038d0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_LAYOUT")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb039a0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_MATERIAL")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03ba0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_MLEADERSTYLE")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05150>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_MLINESTYLE")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03970>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_PLOTSETTINGS")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03990>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_PLOTSTYLENAME")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038e0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_SCALELIST")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb050c0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_TABLESTYLE")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03c60>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_VISUALSTYLE")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03ef0>)
                                    (3 . "ACAD_WIPEOUT_VARS")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05800>)
                                    (3 . "ACDB_RECOMPOSE_DATA")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05350>)
                                    (3 . "AcDbVariableDictionary")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb03ae0>)
                                    (3 . "ENVIRONMENT")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05750>)
                                    (3 . "FERRO")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05910>)
                                    (3 . "POS_FERRO")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05930>)
                                    (3 . "POSIZIONAMENTO_FERRO")
                                    (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05880>)
)
```

Now I want to discover what's inside of "FERRO"

```
(dictsearch (namedobjdict) "FERRO")
```

And I get:

```
    ((-1 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05910>) (0 . "DICTIONARY")
                                (5 . "1F9")
                                (102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS")
                                (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)
                                (102 . "}")
                                (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)
                                (100 . "AcDbDictionary")
                                (280 . 0)
                                (281 . 1)
                                (3 . "1")
                                (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05920>)
```

)

This is not what I was expecting to find.. "Ferro" should contain information about dimension, number and type of a rod.

Maybe I've to dig more but at this point I don't know how to do that.

This is the difference if I add another rod:

```
    ((-1 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05910>) (0 . "DICTIONARY")
                                (5 . "1F9")
                                (102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS")
                                (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)
                                (102 . "}")
                                (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)
                                (100 . "AcDbDictionary")
                                (280 . 0)
                                (281 . 1)
                                (3 . "1")
                                (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05920>)
                                (3 . "2")
                                (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05b00>)
```

)

So it adds a `(3 . "%progressive number%") (350 . entity name)` and maybe it changes the acad_reactors (but how? how to see the reactors?)

Answer (score 0):

`(entget (namedobjdict)))` returns you the AutoCAD Named Object Dictionary which represent the mandatory and unique AutoCAD dictionary. All DWG contains this dictionary, and you cannot replace or delete this one.

`(dictsearch (namedobjdict) "FERRO")` when you call this function, AutoCAD returns you the *FERRO* entry in that dictionary. `(0 . "DICTIONARY") (100 . "AcDbDictionary")` means that the object returned to you is also a dictionary, which is by the way the recommended approach by Autodesk. Never store any object directly into the Named Object Dictionary (NOD), instead, create an intermediate dictionary for your application. That seems to be the case here.

`(102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS") (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>) (102 . "}") (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)` is an AutoCAD internal reference. In a dictionary, all dictionary elements (whether they are simple objects or dictionaries)' have their owner as AutoCAD Reactor. This is for AutoCAD to detect when an object is getting modified or deleted. So the owner dictionary can remove the element key from its entry list when the sub-object is delete for example. You can see that the entry `(330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)` above is the same as the `(-1 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb038c0>)` entry you had in the first call. Meaning the 2nd dictionary reactor object is the owner dictionary (in this case the NOD)

Last, but not least, a dictionary is a list of a  pair. In your case, you got `(3 . "1") (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05920>) (3 . "2") (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ffb05b00>)`, which means you got 2 entries with key *"1"* and *"2"*, and each of them has an associated object which is probably the object you were expecting?

`(setq ferroDict (entget (dictsearch (namedobjdict) "FERRO")))
(setq ferro1 (entget (dictsearch ferroDict  "1")))
(setq ferro1 (entget (dictsearch ferroDict  "2")))
...`

If these object are *your dimensions*, this is how you can reach them.